# MongoDb query to match and remove elements from an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wana query and remove an id from the **facilities** which stores an array of **facility Ids.**
My Schema.

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"),
        "account" : {
            "createdOn" : ISODate("2016-02-19T10:31:32.918Z"),

        },
        "appointments" : [],
        "facilities" : [ 
            ObjectId("vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv"),
            ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

I tried this but Its deleting the whole schema??

```
  this.remove({ '_id': id, facilities :  { "$in" : [facilityId]} })
```

Here the **id** is the ID of this schema and **facilityId** is an id from the facilities. Any help would be very grateful??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep the document and remove an element from the "facilities" array? Is this it?

If so, you don't want to "*remove*", but "*update*" your document.

It would go somehow like this:

```
update(
  {
    "_id": id
  },
  {
    $pullAll:
    {
      "facilities": [facilityId]
    }
  }
)
```

PS: I assumed you already have your document id on hands when you want to modify it. If not, you could query by the "facilities" fields (with *$in* operator, like you did), and, in that case, you would better have an index on it. You could also, as the other answers mention, have an empty document on the query field, but this tends to perform very poorly.

Comment: You would better have an index on the "facilities" field, to avoid searching you entire collection.

Comment: thanks it works, but just a question why $pullAll, while others mentioned  only $pull

Comment: See that I edited the answer and removed the criteria on the "facilities" field for the query. You don't need it if you have your document id. Regarding $pullAll instead of $pull, it seemed more appropriate, according to the documentation. $pull accepts conditions (more-than, less-than, not, etc), and $pullAll is simpler, it just removes the exact matches of a given value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) directive for that.

Given you inserts elements in the pulling collection as seen below:

```
db.pulling.insert(
[
{
   _id: 1,
   fruits: [ "apples", "pears", "oranges", "grapes", "bananas" ],
   vegetables: [ "carrots", "celery", "squash", "carrots" ]
},
{
   _id: 2,
   fruits: [ "plums", "kiwis", "oranges", "bananas", "apples" ],
   vegetables: [ "broccoli", "zucchini", "carrots", "onions" ]
}
]
);
```

You can then remove the carrots with:

```
db.pulling.update(
    { },
    { $pull: { fruits: { $in: [ "apples", "oranges" ] }, vegetables: "carrots" } },
    { multi: true }
);
```

The $pull expression applies the condition to each element of the results array as though it were a top-level document.

Answer (score 1):

With [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to do that

```
db.facilityIds.update(
    { },
    { $pull: {facilities :  { "$in" : [facilityId]} }} },
    { multi: true }
)
```