# How to remove elements of an array based on the array element's data in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

How to write a Mongo query to remove elements of an array if it contain specific data?

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("ajdi293akjf83rhfsf398"),
    "one": "oneData",
    "two": [
        {
         "_id":ObjectId("akjf82ijikfj83jkfkj3"),
         "value": 1
        },
        {
         "_id":ObjectId("akjf82ijikfj83jkfkj3"),
         "value": 2
        },
        {
         "_id":ObjectId("akjf82ijikfj83jkfkj3"),
         "value": 1
        }
        ]
}
```

Need to remove the elements of `two` if the the elements contains `value` as `1`

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("ajdi293akjf83rhfsf398"),
    "one": "oneData",
    "two": [
        {
         "_id":ObjectId("akjf82ijikfj83jkfkj3"),
         "value": 2
        }
        ]
}
```

Please tell me how to achieve this
Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Doe, can you show us what you've tried? It will give us better context and be able to help you better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDb query to match and remove elements from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555167/mongodb-query-to-match-and-remove-elements-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) command with [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator can do the trick.

You can use:

```
    db.collection.update( {} ,
                          { $pull: {two : {value : 1} } },
                          { multi: true });
```